# Given transformation matrix, what is the area of the resulting figure?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given transformation matrix $$T=\begin{bmatrix}10&4\\3&8\end{bmatrix}$$
Applied to the points A(4,2) B(4,6) C(10,2) D(10,6) calculate the area of the resaulting figure.
So far I applied the transformation matrix to the given points:
\begin{bmatrix}10&4\\3&8\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}4&4&10&10\\2&6&2&6\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}48&64&108&124\\28&60&46&78\end{bmatrix} and the area before apllying transformation mtrix is 6×4=24 but I do not have any clue how to calculate the area after applying the transformation matrix, so, please help me and explain to me step by step how to find it.

Comment: Have you learned anything about the relationship between area and determinant?

Comment: Hint: the area will increase by a factor of $ \operatorname{Det} (A)$.

Comment: Also, even if you don't know anything about determinants, draw the resulting figure; you should find that it's a parallelogram (bonus points if you know why this is!) and so you can either use the standard $bh$ formula for the area of a parallelogram, or split it along a diagonal into two congruent triangles and use something like Heron's formula for the area of a triangle. It's probably a good idea to try this anyway, just to double-check your calculation with the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant scales area by $|\det(T)|$, so you may just calculate the area of the figure in the domain.

The original figure is a rectangle with area $4(6)=24$. Your determinant is $68$. So the area of the resulting figure is 
$$
68(24)=1632
$$